# Recrear un formulario hecho con etiquetas html y bootstrap utilizando helpers de asp.net

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Diseñé un formulario utilizando solamente etiquetas html y bootstrap v.4.4.1

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Identificación</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Identificación" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Nombre</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" aria-label="First name" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer nombre">
                            <input type="text" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo nombre">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

queda de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero recrear el mismo ejemplo con helpers de asp.net:

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usuario_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label input-group-text" })
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario_Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usuario_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usuario_nombre_01, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label input-group-text" })
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario_nombre_01, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nombre 1" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usuario_nombre_01, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario_nombre_02, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usuario_nombre_02, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

y los textbox pierden los estilos, y no entiendo cual es la razón, por ende no sé corregirla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código HTML generado por .net?

Comment: Cuando dices que pierden los estilos, a que te refieres?, yo los veo iguales. También indica el modelo de la Vista por favor.

Comment: Los EditorFor no tomaron las clases de bootstrap, en las imágenes no se aprecia.